# How to log unit test entry and leave in MSTest

Tags: logging, mstest

I'm using MSTest and I want to write log entry before test executes and after it finishes. 
Obviously I don't want to add custom logging code at the beginning and end of each test - it would only make the test unreadable and seemed like a lot of effort (I have > 500 tests)

Using *TestInitialize* and *TestCleanup* seemed like the way to go but I can't get the test name.

Does anyone knows how to do this?

Comment: and why do you need the test name ? If you can tell us what you're trying to achieve using logging, maybe i could give a better answer.

Comment: @Gishu - I have a long log file from all of the tests and I want to see in that log what test the current entry belong to. By adding logging before and after each test I can "bound" the test's information

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In MSTest, the name of the test case is available in the [test context property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.testcontext.testname(v=VS.100).aspx). So to access it in the test initialize (as well as test cleanup) method, you can use something like this: -

```
    [TestInitialize()]
    public void MyTestInitialize() 
    {
        if (string.Equals(**TestContext.TestName**, "TestMethod1", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        { 
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

We use [nLog](http://nlog-project.org/) for logging and an base class for test initialize and test cleanup that logs if a test has passed or not.

This is the base class:

```
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using NLog;

namespace Tests
{
    public class TestBase
    {
        private static readonly Logger Logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();

        public TestContext TestContext { get; set; }

        [TestCleanup]
        public void TestCleanup()
        {
            string testName = string.Format("{0}.{1}", TestContext.FullyQualifiedTestClassName, TestContext.TestName);
            UnitTestOutcome currentTestOutcome = TestContext.CurrentTestOutcome;
            string message = string.Format("Test '{0}' {1}", testName, currentTestOutcome.ToString().ToUpperInvariant());
            if (currentTestOutcome != UnitTestOutcome.Passed)
            {
                Logger.Error(message);
            }
            else
            {
                Logger.Info(message);
            }
        }

        [TestInitialize]
        public void TestInitialize()
        {
            string testName = string.Format("{0}.{1}", TestContext.FullyQualifiedTestClassName, TestContext.TestName);
            Logger.Info("Started with test '{0}'", testName);
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the use of it

```
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;

namespace Tests
{
    [TestClass]
    public class JustTest : TestBase
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void Fail()
        {
            Assert.IsTrue(false);
        }

        [TestMethod]
        public void Pass()
        {
            Assert.IsTrue(true);
        }
    }
}
```

here is the part from log file

```
Started with test 'Tests.JustTest.Fail'
Test 'Tests.JustTest.Fail' FAILED

Started with test 'Tests.JustTest.Pass'
Test 'Tests.JustTest.Pass' PASSED
```

Comment: Your answer could be greatly improved by adding some explanation of what your code does.

Answer (score 0):

Update: Ok now I see what you're getting at. Bad news is I don't use MSTest or a MSTest fixture to find out..

In NUnit, you could

```
>"nunit-console.exe" API_Tests.dll /out:My.log /labels
```

THis outputs the following log file

```
***** Test.Gumba.API_Tests.Tests.ArithmeticProgression.DummyTest2
Woohoo! made it till test2
***** Test.Gumba.API_Tests.Tests.ArithmeticProgression.GeneratesTheRightProgressionAsSpecifiedByTheUser
Try#0 failed. due to 0. Retrying NUnit.Framework.AssertionException:   Expected is <System.Int32[10]>, actual is <System.Int32[0]>
<snipped>...
```

I was [looking at the command line switches](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182489%28VS.80%29.aspx) for **MSTest** and the following looks interesting

```
mstest /testcontainer:Some.dll /detail:testname
```

--------------- previous answer follows -----
To answer your question to the point, 'Execute around' methods can be done using a method that takes a delegate. However if you could elaborate on why you need this, maybe there is a better solution to achieve whatever it is you're after

e.g.

```
private void LogAround(Action action)
{
  // log entry with calling method name using StackTrace class
  action();
  // log exit
}
```

and calls would be

```
Do( delegate {
  // test code
});
```

Comment: unfortunately that means that I would need to add this code to all of may present and future tests hurting their readability. I would also need to make sure all of the devs on the team use this in all their tests...
 I want a solution that "aromatically" adds logging to all of my tests